# How to change the Size of SectionIndexTitles in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, xcode4.2

Can any one tell me, is it possible to change the default size of sectionIndexTitles in UITableView? If Yes then how?

Comment: You cannot change the size. Your only solution to customize the IndexTitles is to create it your own AFAIK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  for(UILabel *aView in [tableView subviews]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"frame:%@",aView);
        if([[[aView class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"]) 
         {

            aView.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18.0];

        }
    }
```

You can customise this as per your needs.

Comment: I am asking how to change the the size? what should i implement inside changeSectionIndexTitleSize?

Comment: hi i am just wondering was this rejected by apple if accessing UITableViewIndex directly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

in your UITableViewDelegate as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate)

Here's an example:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  UIView *headerView = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 60)] autorelease];
  [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

  UILabel * headerLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 60)];
  [headerLabel setBackgroundColor:HEXCOLOR(0x952039FF)];

  [headerLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  [headerLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor grayColor]];


  CGRect frame = headerLabel.frame;
  frame.origin = CGPointMake(20,frame.origin.y);
  headerLabel.frame = frame;

  [headerLabel setText:[self sectionTitles:section]];
  [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];
  [headerLabel release];

  return headerView;
```

}

`sectionTitles` refers to a simple function returning the section titles.